# PrimeFaces AutoComplete error

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am facing a strange problem with p:autoComplete, I get following error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "player"

My code is as below

xhtml

```
<p:autoComplete id="schedChemAC" value="#{testMB.selectedPlayer}" completeMethod="#{testMB.completePlay}" process="@this" var="m" itemLabel="#{m.player}" itemValue="#{m}" converter="#{testConverter}">
     <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{testMB.onSelectFrstL}" process="@this"/>
</p:autoComplete>
```

MBean

```
public List<Player> getSelectedPlayer() {
    return selectedPlayer;
}

public void setSelectedPlayer(List<Player> selectedPlayer) {
    this.selectedPlayer = selectedPlayer;
}

public void getName() {
    playerName = playerSession.getAll();
}

public List<Player> completePlay(String query) {
    List<Player> suggestion = new ArrayList<Player>();
    if (playerName == null) {
        getName();
    }
    for (Player c : playerName) {
        if (c.getPlayer().toUpperCase().contains(query.toUpperCase())) {
            suggestion.add(c);
        }
    }
    return suggestion;
}

public void onSelectFrstL(SelectEvent event) {

}
```

Converter

```
@Named(value = "testConverter")
public class TestConverter implements Converter {

@EJB
PlayerSession playSession;
public static List<Player> playLst;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

    if (playLst == null) {
        playLst = playSession.getAll();
    }
    if (value.trim().equals("")) {
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(value);

            for (Player c : playLst) {
                if (c.getPk() == number) {
                    return c;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

    if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return String.valueOf(((Player) value).getPk());
    }
}
```

}

I am not able to find what is wrong in the above code, if i remove the var,itemValue,itemLabel,converter part then it works fine but once i put the var,itemValue,itemLabel,converter code (as given in prime showcase) i get the above error.
Kindly guide me on what is that i am doing wrong or what is that i should check.

Note: My sample table has only two columns, pk(int) & player(string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, its basically if i Pass a List to value(AutoComplete) then the Multiple="true" has be used. Whereas to just do one selection i need to pass only Player object to value(AutoComplete).
Hope this helps somebody else who post without understanding how it works (like me).

Comment: The error is not informative. Thank you for figuring this one out.